# A single reference of Real Analysis/Calculus with following content

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request

There are many books on this subject.

Since, for teaching the course, I am searching, whether there is a single book which can be completely followed during the semester, and which contains the following topics. The following topics mostly either do not come in book, or very short highlight of these topics is given in such books.

(1) Construction of natural numbers, well-ordering principle, with rigorous definitions and proofs.

(2) Construction of integers, rationals, reals, with basic theorems (with proof) (Although students may be familiar with {\it use of theorems}, they may not have come before the thorough understanding of them, up to some extent. I mean, I do not want to see just statements of basic theorems on natural numbers, rationals, reals, etc. I want to see their systematic construction, with rigorous proofs!)

(3) Multivariable calculus (including Gauss divergence theorem, Stokes theorem, Greens theorem, with proofs).

Comment: Tao's *Analysis I* seems to have a fair amount of coverage of (1) and (2), but I'm afraid it doesn't touch (3)(at least explicitly). Nevertheless it's an excellent textbook for a first course in Analysis.

Comment: I think you're looking for something that doesn't exist. Anything that covers (1) and (2) at the level you desire would take several volumes before getting to (3). There are some multi-volume treatises on analysis (one I'm aware of, but don't recall enough about it to search for it (1960s?), is an English translation of a Russian multi-volume treatise) that *might* cover all this material. However, anything that does (1) and (2), and later (3), will almost certainly cover quite a bit of metric and topological notions before getting to (3).

Comment: To me your $(1),(2)$ are in sync but rather orthogonal to $(3)$. Multi variable calculus is a rather very difficult subject (theory and practice both) and just does not fit in with a course which covers $(1),(2)$.